# circular dependency and updateMany is not a function errors in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, orm

I have two files, `questions.js` and `users.js`, both of which are Mongoose models. I have implemented pre and post functions that are triggered before and after a save event. For example, when I save a user, it successfully updates the "evaluation" list attribute with the available topics from the "topics" document.

However, I encounter an issue when I add a new topic. The post function fails (that is supposed to push into the evaluation list of all the users the new topic), and I receive the following error message:
`Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'updateMany' of module exports inside circular dependency TypeError: User.updateMany is not a function.`

Upon investigation, I noticed that the circular dependency is caused because `topic.js` imports `users.js` and `users.js` imports `topic.js`. I need this mutual import because both models require access to each other for their respective pre and post save methods.

I'm not sure if the circular dependency is directly causing the "updateMany is not a function" error. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the pre and post functions work correctly without the error?
topics.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require("./users")

const questionAnswerSchema = new Schema({
    question: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    answers: {
      type: [String],
      required: true
    }
  },{_id: false});
  
  const Topics = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    questionAnswers: {
      type: [questionAnswerSchema],
      required: true
    }
  });

  Topics.post('save', async function (doc, next) {
    try {
      const updatedTopic = doc.toObject();
      await User.updateMany({}, { $push: { evaluations: { name: updatedTopic.name, correctAnswers: 0, wrongAnswers: 0 } } });
    } catch (error) {
       next(error)
    }
  });
  
  const Topic = mongoose.model("topic", Topics);
  module.exports = Topic;
```

users.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
const Topic = require('./topics.js')

const Topics = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "The topic requires a name",
  },
  correctAnswers: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  wrongAnswers: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
})

const User = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "The user requires a name",
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: "The user requires a password"
  },
  evaluations: {
    type: [Topics],
    default: []
  }
});

User.pre('save', function(next) {
  let user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

User.pre('save', async function(next) {
  if (this.isNew) {
    try {
      const topics = await Topic.find().select('name').lean();
      this.evaluations = topics.map(topic => ({
        name: topic.name,
        correctAnswers: 0,
        wrongAnswers: 0
      }));
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  }
  next();
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", User);
module.exports = User;
```